# uninitialized value detected by valgrind : why and where?

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this simple function :

```
template <>
std::string get_yaml_attribute(const YAML::Node& node, const std::string& attribute, const std::string& section)
{
    std::string value;
    try
    {
        value = node[attribute].as<std::string>();
    }
    catch (YAML::BadConversion)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error while converting attribute '"+attribute+"' in section '"+section+"' to string");
    }
    return value;
}
```

in this much larger code : https://bitbucket.org/specmicp/specmicp . Last week I detected a problem when running my code in sspecific setting (https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/122). I think it's a problem with uninitialized variables. I run my code using valgrind, and see a long list of errors, which seems to be related to the previously shown function.

```
==2561== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2561==    at 0x4C2F128: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:454)
==2561==    by 0x40EB1B6: specmicp::io::save_yaml(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, YAML::Emitter&) (char_traits.h:267)
==2561==    by 0x403A26E: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::save_solution(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:102)
==2561==    by 0x404D4A: specmicp::run_formulation(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&&, std::shared_ptr<specmicp::database::DataContainer> const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolverOptions const&) (specmicp.cpp:260)
==2561==    by 0x40C2B6: specmicp::run_specmicp(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&) (specmicp.cpp:192)
==2561==    by 0x4041E1: main (specmicp.cpp:148)
==2561==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2561==    at 0x40E9809: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > specmicp::io::get_yaml_attribute<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(YAML::Node const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (yaml.cpp:132)
==2561==
==2561== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==2561==    at 0x679FDE0: __writev_nocancel (in /lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==2561==    by 0x5A488C4: std::__basic_file<char>::xsputn_2(char const*, long, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==2561==    by 0x5A8716F: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==2561==    by 0x5AAE0E5: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==2561==    by 0x40EB1C4: specmicp::io::save_yaml(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, YAML::Emitter&) (ostream:561)
==2561==    by 0x403A26E: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::save_solution(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:102)
==2561==    by 0x404D4A: specmicp::run_formulation(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&&, std::shared_ptr<specmicp::database::DataContainer> const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolverOptions const&) (specmicp.cpp:260)
==2561==    by 0x40C2B6: specmicp::run_specmicp(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&) (specmicp.cpp:192)
==2561==    by 0x4041E1: main (specmicp.cpp:148)
==2561==  Address 0x75cc2ef is 175 bytes inside a block of size 2,766 alloc'd
==2561==    at 0x4C2C56F: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==2561==    by 0x4E86D39: std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >, unsigned long, char const&) (in /usr/lib64/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.3)
==2561==    by 0x4E86B61: YAML::ostream_wrapper::write(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib64/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.3)
==2561==    by 0x4EA00DB: YAML::Emitter::Write(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib64/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.3)
==2561==    by 0x406E300: operator<< (emitter.h:175)
==2561==    by 0x406E300: format_aqueous_molalities (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:335)
==2561==    by 0x406E300: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::format_solution(specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&, YAML::Emitter&) [clone .constprop.119] (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:171)
==2561==    by 0x4063CB0: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::set_yaml_emitter(specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&, YAML::Emitter&) [clone .constprop.118] (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:119)
==2561==    by 0x403A263: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::save_solution(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:101)
==2561==    by 0x404D4A: specmicp::run_formulation(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&&, std::shared_ptr<specmicp::database::DataContainer> const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolverOptions const&) (specmicp.cpp:260)
==2561==    by 0x40C2B6: specmicp::run_specmicp(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&) (specmicp.cpp:192)
==2561==    by 0x4041E1: main (specmicp.cpp:148)
==2561==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==2561==    at 0x40E9809: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > specmicp::io::get_yaml_attribute<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(YAML::Node const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (yaml.cpp:132)
==2561==
```

EDIT: Line 132 corresponds to the line "std::string value"

I don't understand where the problem is. Initializing 'value' does not change the output (and I wouldn't expect it to). IS it a problem with valgrind and exceptions ? Or am I blind and missing the obvious ?

EDIT : A similar error (shown below) is obtained when modifying the function to a one-liner (no error verification)

YAML::Node is an object created by the yaml-cpp library (https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp)

```
template <>
std::string get_yaml_attribute(const YAML::Node& node, const std::string& attribute, const std::string& section)
{
    return node[attribute].as<std::string>();
}
```

error :

```
==6522== Syscall param writev(vector[...]) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==6522==    at 0x6361DE0: __writev_nocancel (in /lib64/libc-2.23.so)
==6522==    by 0x5A488C4: std::__basic_file<char>::xsputn_2(char const*, long, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==6522==    by 0x5A8716F: std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==6522==    by 0x5AAE0E5: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==6522==    by 0x5AAE4D6: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==6522==    by 0x5614FD: specmicp::io::save_yaml(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, YAML::Emitter&) (yaml.cpp:82)
==6522==    by 0x48E319: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::save_solution(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:102)
==6522==    by 0x486AA6: specmicp::run_formulation(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&&, std::shared_ptr<specmicp::database::DataContainer> const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolverOptions const&) (specmicp.cpp:260)
==6522==    by 0x486256: specmicp::run_specmicp(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&) (specmicp.cpp:192)
==6522==    by 0x485B7E: main (specmicp.cpp:148)
==6522==  Address 0x71c92af is 175 bytes inside a block of size 2,766 alloc'd
==6522==    at 0x4C2C56F: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==6522==    by 0x4E86D39: std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >, unsigned long, char const&) (in /usr/lib64/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.3)
==6522==    by 0x4E86B61: YAML::ostream_wrapper::write(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib64/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.3)
==6522==    by 0x4EA00DB: YAML::Emitter::Write(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (in /usr/lib64/libyaml-cpp.so.0.5.3)
==6522==    by 0x49422D: YAML::operator<<(YAML::Emitter&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) (emitter.h:175)
==6522==    by 0x490965: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::format_aqueous_molalities(specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&, YAML::Emitter&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:335)
==6522==    by 0x48EAF5: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::format_solution(specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&, YAML::Emitter&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:171)
==6522==    by 0x48E559: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::set_yaml_emitter(specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&, YAML::Emitter&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:119)
==6522==    by 0x48E306: specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolutionSaver::save_solution(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolution const&) (adimensional_system_solution_saver.cpp:101)
==6522==    by 0x486AA6: specmicp::run_formulation(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&&, std::shared_ptr<specmicp::database::DataContainer> const&, specmicp::AdimensionalSystemSolverOptions const&) (specmicp.cpp:260)
==6522==    by 0x486256: specmicp::run_specmicp(specmicp::io::YAMLConfigHandle&) (specmicp.cpp:192)
==6522==    by 0x485B7E: main (specmicp.cpp:148)
```

EDIT:

After linking statically to yaml-cpp the error is now

```
...
==5783==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==5783==    at 0x5AAC2D: YAML::Scanner::ScanQuotedScalar() (in /home/manawy/princeton/progra/specmicp-build/src/bin/specmicp/specmicp)
```

I guess it's a bug in the library. I'm not sure how it would propagates to my code though. I have to analyze it.

Comment: Which line is yaml.cpp:132?

Comment: I edited my initial message. Line 132 corresponds to the line "std::string value", though changing that line by initializing the variable does not seem do modify the error message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I knew how to do it I would have included it. I don't know where the problem is. All the simple examples I made work as I expect them to do.

Comment: Just start ripping code out until it goes away.  once it does you know where the problem is.  Then you just need to start ripping out the non-problematic code from the file until you get something that is small but still throws the error.

Comment: Could you provide also information about platform, compiler and valgrind version?

Comment: I remove all the error verification and obtained a similar error (I edited the post). I saw that dynamic linking may cause problem, I'm going to see if I can change that.

Comment: It's on linux with gcc 5.4 and valgrind 3.12

Comment: It seems likely the code has thrown something other than a YAML::BadConversion. Try catching everything and putting in a diagnostic print.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean : if there was another exception, the program would abort

Comment: Changing to a static linking of the yaml-cpp library changes the error (the post was edited)

Comment: If not yet done, you could add the valgrind option --track-origins=yes to show where the uninit value comes from.